# Script in bash to get all certificates names in a directory

Tags: linux, bash

I'm creating a script in bash that uses the command:

`openssl x509 -in <cert> -noout -text | grep 'Issuer\|Not After' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'`

and check all certificate files in the directory, I used the command
`ls -l | grep .crt | cut -d " " -f11 > test.txt` 
to get the following certificate list:

```
client.crt
client1.crt
client12.crt
client2.crt
client3.crt
server12.crt
server2.crt
```

however when I run:

`for i in test.txt;do openssl x509 -in $i -noout -text | grep 'Issuer|Not After' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//';done`

I get the following output:

```
unable to load certificate
140075503359296:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

Comment: I don't know the intrinsincs of openssl, but your loop iterates exactly once, with `i` set to `test.txt`. Therefore you are executing a `openssl x509 -in test.txt -nout -text`.  Is this really what you want?

Answer (score 2):

You're not iterating over the files listed in your `test.txt`, your executing openssl against that very file.

What you really want to do is this:

```
while read -r i
do
openssl x509 -in "$i" -noout -text | grep 'Issuer|Not After' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'
done < test.txt
```

P.S.: I did not verify that your openssl magic works, just fixed the loop logic.

Comment: Very thank you!
It's works very well!

Comment: Btw, did you understand why your `for i in test.txt` didn't work?